# Views 'Search terms' exposed filter not working in PROD but works locally

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-search

I know this is a lame question but I have a view which has title, body and taxonomies. I just need to search them all together which is achieved by Search Terms.

The problem is that I can perfectly do it in my local copy but when I took all the changes to PROD it doesn't work. The weird thing is that it's not completely not-working. It does show some results but not all of them.

I just don't know how to debug this but I'll be grateful if you people cuold assist me as to how I should approach this problem.

The local is running exact copy of PROD of DB and files. Settings.php and .htaccess might be changed. PHP version and MySQL version is also different.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-indexing the site?
This can be done from /admin/config/search/settings

From there you can see the index status in percentage.

If your search is working now, perhaps this was the case...